# How to get table names from user in pyodbc while avoiding SQL injection?

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, python-3.x, pyodbc

I have the following code which is completely safe and the user cannot input anything which could lead to SQL injection.

```
value = get_value_from_user_input()
query = \
    """
    SELECT *
    FROM TestTable
    WHERE CompareValue = ?
    """
cursor.execute(query, value)
```

But what if I would need to get the table name from the user. I can't do it like this, because that leaves me vulnerable to SQL injection;

```
table_name = get_table_name_from_user_input()
query = \
    f"""
    SELECT *
    FROM {table_name}
    WHERE CompareValue = 1234
    """
cursor.execute(query)
```

And I also cannot do it like this (which would be logical imo), because it gives an error.

```
table_name = get_table_name_from_user_input()
query = \
    """
    SELECT *
    FROM ?
    WHERE CompareValue = 1234
    """
cursor.execute(query, table_name)
```

So how should I do this?

**Extra info:**

The program is for use inside my company and all the users of the software have admin rights to the database. It might be little bit pointless to not allow them injecting SQL, since they can do raw SQL queries anyways. I just want to be pedantic about it and not allow my program to execute random SQL. The `get_table_name_from_user_input()` actually gets the table name from a config file which describes the database structure, so it can easily be edited by the user if someday the table names change in the database, without the need to touch the source code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get a list of the valid table names directly from the database by using pyodbc's [Cursor#tables](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Cursor#tablestablenone-catalognone-schemanone-tabletypenone) function:

```python
crsr = cnxn.cursor()
table_names = [x[2] for x in crsr.tables(tableType='TABLE')]
print(table_names)  # ['customer', 'invoice', ...]
```

As you have noted, you can't use parameters to supply object (e.g., table or column) *names* to a query, but you can use the T-SQL [QUOTENAME](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function to help ensure that the (dynamic) SQL you construct is valid.

It's good that you are on the lookout for possible SQL Injection issues, but not all dynamic SQL is evil. Sometimes, as in this case, it is necessary; you just need to take appropriate steps to protect yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have too many tables, you could check if the requested table name exists in a list of valid table names.

```
tables = ["customers", "vendors", "products"]

user_inputs = ["products", "invoices", "vendors WHERE CompareValue=1234; DROP TABLE customers; --"]

query = "SELECT * FROM placeholder WHERE CompareValue=1234;"

for user_input in user_inputs:
  if user_input in tables:
    print(query.replace("placeholder", user_input))
  else:
    print(f"'{user_input}' is not a valid table")
```

Gives the following results

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE CompareValue=1234;
'invoices' is not a valid table
'vendors WHERE CompareValue=1234; DROP TABLE customers; --' is not a valid table
```

This snippet in repl: https://repl.it/repls/SeveralAnimatedAutomaticvectorization

Comment: If you read my extra information section it explains why I cannot do it like this. I would want a way to check the validity from the database itself.